# Cocoa/Objective-C NSButton event handling?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm wondering how to handle an event on NSButton click, I've searched all over the internet and found lots of things like RightMouse button event handling, event handling on mouseup, event handling in c++, etc. but nothing that's just normal event handling, seems like everyone knows it already so I can't find any information about it? And I'm doing it all without .nib files or any kind of builder, it's pure text, so how do I handle button click event, I already have window and button created?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
NSButton *myButton = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
[myButton setTarget:self];
[myButton setAction:@selector(myMethodToCallOnClick:)];
```

Comment: Oh, thanks that's what I was looking for, knew it was something easy as heck but just couldn't find out what

Comment: Ok. Happy it helped. I guess you can validate the answer ;)

Comment: As soon as possible, giving me error that you can't mark answer correct within 4 minutes... I'll mark it when I can